# Enviar token por Post Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Hola me encuentro trabajando en una aplicación Angular(FrontEnd) que consume una Api desde Python Flask(BackEnd), deseo enviar por método Post una cadena de caracteres que almaceno en mi Localstorage por medio de otra petición llamado token pero este me envía error 400 como si no recibiera los parámetros.

Al enviar un formulario con un campo de correo este ejecuta la función onSend con dos métodos que contienen las endPoint a consumir en el servicio, claveTemporal me genera el token y se lo paso a enviarCorreo.

```
   // api.Service.ts

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  public token: any;
  public email: Email;
  public usuario: Usuario;
  public apiURL: string;

  constructor( public http: HttpClient, public helper: HelperComponent) 
  {
    this.apiURL = GLOBAL.url;
  }

  claveTemporal(usuario: Usuario): Observable<Usuario> {
    const params = this.helper.convertirParametros(usuario);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www- form-urlencoded'
    });
    return this.http.post(this.apiURL + '/users/claveTemporal', params, {headers});
  }

  enviarCorreo(token: any): Observable<any> {
    console.log('DATOS TOKEN', token);
    const params = this.helper.convertirParametros(token);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    return this.http.post(this.apiURL + '/auth/enviarCorreo', params, {headers});}
  }
}
```

---

```
// enviorCorreo.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'claveTemporal',
  templateUrl: './claveTemporal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./claveTemporal.component.css'],
  providers: [ApiService, HelperComponent],
})
export class ClaveTemporalComponent implements OnInit {
  submitted = false;
  public mensaje: any;
  public usuario: Usuario;
  public email: Email;
  public errorService: any;
  public token: any;

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSend(form) {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.apiService.claveTemporal(this.usuario).subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
        this.mensaje = 'Redireccionando Espera un Momento...';
        this.errorService = null;
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(resp));
      },
      error => {
        this.mensaje = null;
        this.errorService = error.error;
       this.token = null;
      }
    );

    const correoLocal = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const objectLocal = JSON.parse(correoLocal);
    this.token = objectLocal.token;
    console.log(this.token);

    this.apiService.enviarCorreo(this.token).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log('CORREO ENVIADO', this.token);
        console.log(response);
        this.router.navigate(['/Contrasena']);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Acá tenés un espacio que no va: 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www- form-urlencoded'. Si el problema no es ese, fijate en el navegador con inspect: 1 errores que salen en la consola. 2 en la parte de network que es lo que se está enviando en términos de headers y parametros. Y por las dudas verificá si el token no debería ser enviado como un header de Authorization.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar la implementación de `HelperComponent`?

Comment: Qué es lo que te da el error `400`? El front o el back? Por que despues del `onSend()`, cuando el observable se resuelve tienes un `this.route.navigate([/Contrasena])` que tambien podria estar generando el error `400`. Y en otra cuestion, es muy grande el texto que vas a enviar (el payload) como para que utilices ese `Content-Type`? Estoy leyendo y parece que solo se utiliza para grandes cantidades de texto y datos binarios (archivos)

Comment: @Juan ` 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www- form-urlencoded'` es una propiedad de un objeto, no debería afectar, supongo...

Comment: Exacto @juan este header no esta enviando nada y por ende no deberia causar problemas.

Comment: Angel el this.router.navigate(['/Contrasena']); es una redireccion en caso de que obtega una respuesta

Comment: gugadev no estoy utilizando un conversor helper

Comment: Sin ver información adicional es dificil diagnosticar el problema. Al margen de esto, el header del content type que se esta usando para hacer el post de clave temporal tiene un espacio que invalida ese header. La función de ese header es que los parámetros que se envian al servidor sean leidos como pares de nombre=valor[&nombre2=valor2] ... . Quizás el servidor es fault tolerant y defaultea al valor correcto, y quizás no. De cualquier forma eso debería corregirse. @Angel